# How to exact match a nginx location?

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I am configuring a nginx revser proxy. The result should be when user type `http://10.21.169.13/mini`, then the request should be `proxy_pass to 192.168.1.56:5000`. Here is the `nginx` config:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name 10.21.169.13;

        location = /mini {
                proxy_pass http://192.168.1.65:5000;
                include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
        }
}
```

The above `location` block never worked with `http://10.21.169.13/mini`. The only `location` block worked is:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name 10.21.169.13;

        location  / {
                proxy_pass http://192.168.1.65:5000;
                include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
        }
}
```

But the above config also match `http://10.21.169.13` request which is too board.

What `location` block will only match 'http://10.21.169.13/mini` and no more?

UPDATE: tried and failed with the following:

```
 location  /mini {
                    proxy_pass http://192.168.1.65:5000;
                    include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
            }

location  /mini/ {
                    proxy_pass http://192.168.1.65:5000;
                    include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
            }
```

The error is `request not found`.

Comment: Look at the access log. The `/mini` may be too restrictive, but the access log may tell you why.

Comment: The access log under /opt/nginx/logs has nothing to be recorded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this out:

```
server {
    listen 80;
  server_name 10.21.169.13;

  # root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    # index index.html index.htm;

  location  / {
        # add something here to handle the root
        # try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

  location  /mini {
    proxy_pass http://192.168.1.65:5000;
    include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
    }

}
```

Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: `srayhunter`, there is 404 Not Found error with the conf above.

Comment: @user938363 you will need to configure the commented out code for your current setup. So if you have a root directory you will need to specify that and then you can uncomment the **try_files** line.

Comment: There is no root. The nginx provides web access for OctoPrint which is a 3D printer management software.

Comment: Im not sure what you should have there, but you might need to setup a root so that the `/mini` is handled properly.